# Enable sqlite in Lazarus ide?

Tags: ide, sqlite, 64-bit, lazarus

I have Lazarus IDE 1.1 (FPC 2.6.1) x64 on windows 7 x64.

When I go in "Package", then "Install/Remove packages", in "do not install" I can select "sqlite3laz 0.4" and move it in the column "install". Then I press "Save and recompile IDE". It compiles for a while then it tells me:

> C:\lazarus\components\sqlite\registersqlite3.pas(1,1) Fatal: Can't find unit sqlite3ds used by registersqlite3

How can I fix this? Thanks!

**edit**

`sqlite3ds.pas` is in `C:\lazarus\fpc\2.6.1\source\packages\fcl-db\src\sqlite` though...

**edit**

found: http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,12930.msg87799.html#msg87799
I'll try the 32bit version...

**edit**

Works with the 32bit version. Can I make it work with the 64bit version?

Answer (score 1):

Is Lazarus actually USING 2.6.1? If lazarus is still using 2.6.0, the directories that hold the 2.6.1 precompiled units might not be searched.

Note that the path you mention is a source path, while Lazarus generally works with FPC units in precompiled (ppu,o) format. Source is only used for debugging (source path) when properly configured, never searched by the compiler (unit path)

Comment: x64 version was using 2.6.1. x86 version I used the latest stable (2.6.0). The icon for sqlite is already in the IDE using 32bit :S